# Django. Взаимодействие администратора и пользователя

Tags: django

Допустим у меня есть страница для пользователя и страница, которая доступна только администраторам `mysite.com/admin/getPost`. Пользователь заходит на `mysite.com/sendPost` пишет текст и нажимает на кнопку `Отправить`. В этот момент администратор смотрит на страницу `mysite.com/admin/getPost`, которая обновляется и на ней появляется текст, отправленный пользователем. Как это реализовать в django ? Если это не реализуется в django, то как это реализовать? . Прошу прощения за детское описание.

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в качестве ответа?

Comment: Код написанный на питоне

Comment: Тут не просто пять строчек кода, минимум 500. Тут либо `longpool`, либо websockets (в сочетании с `Django channels`, разумеется), разграничение прав доступа. С нуля вам тут никто это писать не будет. Либо начните сами, либо наймите фрилансера. Как-то так

Comment: Все зависит от желаемой реализации. Если Вы хотите реализовать взаимодействие как в чате, пользователь пишет и у админа сообщения появляются без перезагрузки страницы, то тут все плохо, ибо как сказали выше нужны вэбсокеты и каналы. Если это не требуется то все на самом деле довольно просто реализуется.